Move focus to another input on macOS Safari after entering username/password with Touch-Id
Simplified form for testing:


function onChange() {
  document.querySelector("input[tabindex='3']").focus()
}
<form>
  <input
    type='text'
    name='username'
    tabindex='1'
    autofocus
    onchange="onChange()"
  >
  <input type='password' name='password' tabindex='2'>
  <input type='text' name='security' tabindex='3'>
</form>



The input "username" with tabIndex 1 receives the focus when the page is loaded.
In Safari on macOS the username/password Touch-Id popup will appear automatically due to the naming of these two input fields.
Touch-Id is triggering the onchange event as expected, but the focusing to the input named 'security' with tabIndex 3 is not happening – the focus stays on the 'username' field.
I know that the onchange event is triggered by Touch-Id because replacing the code with:
onchange="console.log(document.querySelector('input[tabindex=\'3\']'))"

will correctly show the target HTML object <input type='text' name='security' tabindex='3'>.
For testing I also renamed the fields 'username' and 'password' and changed the type of the password field to 'text' and then the code:
onchange="document.querySelector('input[tabindex=\'3\']').focus()"

works perfectly – when leaving the field with tab the cursor jumps from tabIndex 1 to tabIndex 3 as expected and leaves out tabIndex 2.
I also tried several events on the target input – especially onfocus of course – to see if maybe the code works and the focus is "stolen back" by the 'username' field due to the fact that Touch-Id takes its time, but to no avail.
What could be preventing the focus change when the onchange event is triggered by Touch-Id?

What if you just wait until the value is filled in? Touch ID shouldn't return focus to a field it has already filled in? Also, don't use tabindices higher than 0 - seriously, accessibility wise this is actually a no-no. You are forcing user through those inputs, taking away their freedom to explore the page themselves.

@somethinghere This is for a business web app run internally at one company only – not for users in the www. It is mostly a data entering app handled by keyboard strokes only. The tab indices are a requirement. Each user can modify the order and even take input fields out of the tab order entirely in his settings to be able to enter data quicker.

Although I understand your use case, I would still recommend against it, but that's neither here nor there.
